# Getting Sequelize.js library to work on Amazon Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, node-mysql2

So I'm trying to run a lambda on amazon and narrowed down the error finally by testing the lambda in amazons testing console.

The error I got is this.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Please install mysql2 package manually",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "new MysqlDialect (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:14:30)",
    "new Sequelize (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:234:20)",
    "Object.exports.getSequelizeConnection (/var/task/src/twilio/twilio.js:858:20)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/twilio/twilio.js:679:25)",
    "__webpack_require__ (/var/task/src/twilio/twilio.js:20:30)",
    "/var/task/src/twilio/twilio.js:63:18",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/twilio/twilio.js:66:10)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}
```

Easy enough, so I have to install mysql2.  So I added it to my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "test-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.153.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^1.1.20",
    "serverless-dynamodb-autoscaling": "^0.6.2",
    "serverless-webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.13.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.1",
    "qs": "^6.5.1",
    "sequelize": "^4.31.2",
    "serverless": "^1.26.0",
    "serverless-plugin-scripts": "^1.0.2",
    "twilio": "^3.10.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I noticed when I do sls deploy however, it seems to only be packaging some of the modules?

```
Serverless: Package lock found - Using locked versions
Serverless: Packing external modules: babel-runtime@^6.26.0, twilio@^3.10.0, qs@^6.5.1, mailgun-js@^0.13.1, sequelize@^4.31.2, minimi
st@^1.2.0, uuid@^3.1.0
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...

Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
................................
Serverless: Stack update finished...
```

I think this is why it's not working.  **In short, how do I get mysql2 library to be packaged correctly with serverless so my lambda function will work with the sequelize library?**

Please note that **when I test locally my code works fine.**

My serverless file is below

```
service: testapi

# Use serverless-webpack plugin to transpile ES6/ES7
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-plugin-scripts
  # - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  #Define the Stage or default to Staging.
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  webpackIncludeModules: true
  #Define Databases Here
  databaseName: "${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}"
  #Define Bucket Names Here
  uploadBucket: "${self:service}-uploads-${self:custom.stage}"
  #Custom Script setup
  scripts:
    hooks:
      #Script below will run schema changes to the database as neccesary and update according to stage.
      'deploy:finalize':  node database-schema-update.js --stage ${self:custom.stage}
  #Domain Setup
  # customDomain:
  #    basePath: "/"
  #    domainName: "api-${self:custom.stage}.test.com"
  #    stage: "${self:custom.stage}"
  #    certificateName: "*.test.com"
  #    createRoute53Record: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: staging
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    DOMAIN_NAME: "api-${self:custom.stage}.test.com"
    DATABASE_NAME: ${self:custom.databaseName}
    DATABASE_USERNAME: ${env:RDS_USERNAME}
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${env:RDS_PASSWORD}
    UPLOAD_BUCKET: ${self:custom.uploadBucket}
    TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID: ""
    TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN: ""
    USER_POOL_ID: ""
    APP_CLIENT_ID: ""
    REGION: "us-east-1"
    IDENTITY_POOL_ID: ""
    RACKSPACE_API_KEY: ""
  #Below controls permissions for lambda functions.
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:UpdateTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:*"

functions:
  create_visit:
    handler: src/visits/create.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: visits
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
  get_visit:
    handler: src/visits/get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: visits/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
  list_visit:
    handler: src/visits/list.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: visits
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
  update_visit:
    handler: src/visits/update.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: visits/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
  delete_visit:
    handler: src/visits/delete.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: visits/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
  twilio_send_text_message:
    handler: src/twilio/twilio.send_text_message
    events:
      - http:
          path: twilio/sendtextmessage
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
  #This function handles incoming calls and where to route it to.
  twilio_incoming_call:
    handler: src/twilio/twilio.incoming_calls
    events:
      - http:
          path: twilio/calls
          method: post
  twilio_failure:
    handler: src/twilio/twilio.twilio_failure
    events:
      - http:
          path: twilio/failure
          method: post
  twilio_statuschange:
    handler: src/twilio/twilio.statuschange
    events:
      - http:
          path: twilio/statuschange
          method: post
  twilio_incoming_message:
    handler: src/twilio/twilio.incoming_message
    events:
      - http:
          path: twilio/messages
          method: post
  twilio_whisper:
    handler: src/twilio/twilio.whisper
    events:
      - http:
          path: twilio/whisper
          method: post
      - http:
          path: twilio/whisper
          method: get
  twilio_start_call:
    handler: src/twilio/twilio.start_call
    events:
      - http:
          path: twilio/startcall
          method: post
      - http:
          path: twilio/startcall
          method: get

resources:
  Resources:
    uploadBucket:
       Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
       Properties:
         BucketName: ${self:custom.uploadBucket}
    RDSDatabase:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        Engine : mysql
        MasterUsername: ${env:RDS_USERNAME}
        MasterUserPassword: ${env:RDS_PASSWORD}
        DBInstanceClass : db.t2.micro
        AllocatedStorage: '5'
        PubliclyAccessible: true
        #TODO: The Value of Stage is also available as a TAG automatically which I may use to replace this manually being put here..
        Tags:
          -
            Key: "Name"
            Value: ${self:custom.databaseName}
      DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    DNSRecordSet:
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
      Properties:
        HostedZoneName: test.com.
        Name: database-${self:custom.stage}.test.com
        Type: CNAME
        TTL: '300'
        ResourceRecords:
        - {"Fn::GetAtt": ["RDSDatabase","Endpoint.Address"]}
      DependsOn: RDSDatabase
```

UPDATE:: So I confirmed that running sls package --stage dev seems to create this in the zip folder that would eventually upload to AWS.  **This confirms that serverless is not creating the package correctly with the mysql2 reference** for some reason? **Why is this?**

[image]

**webpack config file as requested**

```
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: You may have to add `mysql2` as an external module. Can you show your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: sure one moment, I am using serverless so got to see where they hide that.

Comment: ok added it to bottom of my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to dashmugs comment after some investigation on this page (https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack), there is a section on Forced Inclusion.  I'll paraphrase it here.

> Forced inclusion Sometimes it might happen that you use dynamic
>   requires in your code, i.e. you require modules that are only known at
>   runtime. Webpack is not able to detect such externals and the compiled
>   package will miss the needed dependencies. In such cases you can force
>   the plugin to include certain modules by setting them in the
>   forceInclude array property. However the module must appear in your
>   service's production dependencies in package.json.

```
# serverless.yml
custom:
  webpackIncludeModules:
    forceInclude:
      - module1
      - module2
```

So I simply did this...

```
webpackIncludeModules:
    forceInclude:
      - mysql
      - mysql2
```

Now it works! Hope this helps someone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous helped me, I used this solution: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9489#issuecomment-493304014

The trick is to use `dialectModule` property and override sequelize.

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import mysql2 from 'mysql2'; // Needed to fix sequelize issues with WebPack

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectModule: mysql2, // Needed to fix sequelize issues with WebPack
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
  }
)

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  console.log('Trying to connect via sequelize')
  await sequelize.sync()
  await sequelize.authenticate()
  console.log('=> Created a new connection.')

  // Do something 
}
```

The previous so far works on MySql but is not working with **Postgres**